# Variables vs declarations for simple values

Tags: variables, memory, coding-style, processing, declaration

I am not an amateur programmer, but this question surely sounds somewhat amateurish, that may be because I learned programming by experimentation, tutorials, and advice from forums and stackoverflow among other things.

But, I was just thinking while working with some (javascript) code I was making the other day where I realized with simple numbers I was using in part of some algebra equation I had in there - some of them were being used twice, or a few times, and so I had done what I've done in similar situations. That is, I put them into variables representing them, and then using them in the multiple instances they were needed. Although, this might be obvious, something along the lines of this example:

```
var two = 2;
var seven = 7;
var eighteen = 18;

var calculate = (((seven * 140) / (seven + eighteen)) + ((eighteen * 50) + two) * two);
```

Now I know this calculation makes no sense, but it's not meant to make any sense, it's just a random calculation I made up to illustrate my point.

But the question I have is is this correct? My logic is why set the same value over and over when I can declare it in a variable and then have it served up from memory rather than repeatedly given. Truthfully this question has been in my mind for quite some time, but I never bothered asking it in risk of looking somewhat stupid, but I just decided I just want to know a definitive answer to it once and for all. For example, I remember having a conversation with somebody a long time ago about this very topic, I don't remember who, maybe it was a teacher in some html class in school, or who knows now. But I remember that person telling me that when it comes to simple values like these, it's best to give the actual value there then having it declared beforehand and calling it from memory, because apparently, this calling and reading of this (or those) variable(s) takes more processing than it would to have it set repeatedly when its needed. Obviously a complex value (like my "calculate" variable) would be better declared before and remembered, but with simple values, this is where I'm not 100% sure.

As I said, this question has been at the back of my mind for quite some time, and I just wanted to know for sure the truth on the matter. I've been using this concept (not frequently, just in rare cases where it becomes necessary) on javascript, jQuery, C#, and T-SQL rarely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do what you showed in your example. It's good to *not* have "magic numbers" in code (like 2, 7, and 18), but if you're going to replace them with either macro constants or variables, name them to indicate their purpose. That way, if you have to change a value for some reason, you don't have "two" with a value of 3! "array_stride" with a value of 2 can be changed to value 3 with no confusion.

Now, as to whether or not it's better to put these values in a constant macro literal, or to make variables out of them, that's hard to give a definite answer to. It depends on whether the compiler or whatever can recognize repeated uses of the same constant value, and optimize it to only allocate one piece of storage for it. If it can, it really doesn't matter which you do, as it will store the value in one place and load it wherever needed (with sufficient registers, you might get it kept in a register, which would load faster). If it can't, you'd be better off making a variable. So, perhaps it *would* be better to have a full-fledged variable.

Comment: Well, I use names that associate with the value because its not like I do this a lot, only when the need arises, and when I do this its for a specific part of my code, not like some important variable that gets used repeatedly throughout a large block of code. I name them by there associated value because at the time of writing the code, I can't think of simple way of putting its purpose into actual words, so the quick way for me is to just name for its associated value, and if I change the value - which I have - I also change the name to match the new value. And...

Comment: And, I thank you for your detailed answer of the core of my question. But, you said it depends on the compiler, and I have already said at the bottom of my question that I've done this with javascript, jQuery, C#, and T-SQL (for SQL Server). So, I understand what you said in your answer, but you're answer was generic and it depended on what compiler is in use. Since I explained the types of code I use, surely the compilers are obvious as well. Now that I know what you - Phil Perry - have said on the matter, I would like someone else, or Phil Perry - to please expand on what he said and be...

Comment: What's the point, if you have to go through your code and change all the **two**s to **three**s? You might as well just leave the magic numbers in the code. You never, ever name it "two" for that very reason. You name it "array_stride" or whatever it means, and use that.

Comment: ...specific - taking into account what code I use, and the compilers used therein. An answer in these regards would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, well fine, I don't know, my logic was that it didn't matter to me if I had to rename it or not because this is something I didn't do too often anyways, so it wasn't some kind of burden really. I put the values in variables for better processing/performance - not for my own ease of use. But, fine, let's say I'll take your advice and name them names like "array_stride" like you said. That still doesn't answer the last question I brought up based on your very informative answer you gave above - which I thank you for - but I just wanted you (or anyone) to be more specific - as to how you...

Comment: ...were talking about the compiler, and the compiler would obviously match the codes I mentioned I program in.